# MySQL Queries stored in one table to update values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I've never used stored procedures or functions and only minimally used JOIN functions.

Is there a way to store multiple queries in one place (table, stored procedure, or stored function) that update records in another table. Ideally, I'd like to schedule these queries to run nightly.

My TABLE constantly has new records being added, LINK will typically be NULL, but I need to populate it based on some conditions (I've simplified for this example). I use PRODUCT & a few other columns to determine what the LINK value is.

Query Examples:

> update TABLE set LINK='XYZ' where PRODUCT='X';
>
> update TABLE set LINK='A' where PRODUCT='A' and STYLE='SAMPLE';
>
> update TABLE set LINK='C' where PRODUCT='C' and STYLE='SAMPLE1';
>
> update TABLE set LINK='C2' where PRODUCT='C' and STYLE='SAMPLE2';

Would one possible solution be creating a second table with: PRODUCT='X' = LINK='XYZ' could I then use a JOIN to update my table?

Additionally, is there a way to automatically run these updates on a schedule?

Thank you in advance! Hopefully it makes sense, this is my first post, long time reader.

Comment: If `PRODUCT='X'` always means `STYLE='XYZ'`; then `STYLE` should probably be wherever `PRODUCT` is defined. Of course, you said you've simplified it; so if it is more complicated you could probably go with an INSERT **trigger** and have it happen in real time.

Comment: The problem with only doing a trigger though is needing to update the trigger every time there are new criteria. With a sort of "mapping" table, as you've considered, you only need to update the mapping rules and have the trigger use those instead... but that brings us back to "why have the data in the 'TABLE' table to begin with, when you can just join to the mapping table when needed?"

Comment: @Uueerdo Thank you for your comments here. I'm thinking triggers might be a nice solution, my criteria doesn't change too often, but without some more research into triggers, I'm wondering how difficult it will be to manage those triggers (I'll have about 300 for a database of 23 million rows). I like the idea of real time, but that could also introduce some performance issues I'd think. I need to do some testing on triggers vs a scheduled query.

Comment: Yes, trigger can slow down whatever action (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) they are based on; so testing should be done if speed is critical.

Answer (score 0):

**Schedule queries**

1. Create a text file, e.g. `nightly_update.sql`.
2. Add these queries into `nightly_update.sql` line by line. (Now you can execute all these queries with a `source` command in MySQL: `source nightly_update.sql;`. Note that you should perform the `use your_db_name;` first)
3. On Linux, use the [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to create a timed task. The task should be: 
   to execute a shell script at the specified time.

   `emacs -nw /etc/crontab`, add this line:
   `00 1 * * * root  /home/my/mytable_auto_update.sh  // every 1:00 am to run this script`
4. Write the shell script mentioned before. Here is an example of how to execute SQL commands in a shell script:

   `mysql -u$DB_USER -h$DB_HOST -P$DB_PORT -p$DB_PASS <<\EOF   // you don't need  an '\' in your code
   use $DB_NAME;
   source nightly_update.sql;
   EOF`
5. Restart crond with `sudo service cron restart`.

You should use a certain strategy to avoid duplicate SQL statements, e.g. delete the `nightly_update.sql` after you `source` it, and then create a new one when new query arrived.

**Update your table with json**

As far as I know, you may make it with the help of plug-ins. And MySQL provide a 
[InnoDB memorycached Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html) which provide you NoSQL-style interfaces.

In addition, the memorycached plugin is not that popular, and this is not a recommended approach. Please check the manual carefully if you're interested in it.

Comment: Thanks @walter I'll look into this solution for scheduling my queries. I appreciate you time and input helping me out.